# How to use different versions of google-play-services libs for a project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am in the center point of the major confusion, can I able to get GCM notifications from the latest version of google-play-services.

If no then I need to use older version of google-play-services for GCM, a newer version of google-play-services for Geofence and medium version for location updates.
How can I achieve it in Eclipse project, please give me some of your valuable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you guys give me a reason why down voted? Helps to correct the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use New version of google play services and migrate **GCM** to **FCM** becuse it recomnded by google

Comment: I can't upgrade to the FCM right now because with the one server there is number of application runnning, i can not give the server side update blindly without considering the mobile side problems!!